# Summary of validation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an Angular form (called `saveForm`) that has a bunch of text inputs for bound to a variable called `billingAddress`.  Each input looks something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="billName">Name*</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" title="{{billingAddress.name}}"
               id="billName" name="billName" ng-model="billingAddress.name" required />
        <span class="field-validation-error"
              ng-show="saveForm['billName'].$error.required">
            {{saveForm['billName'].$error.message}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, I have many more inputs (and each input has a different name like `name="billAddress1"` or `name="billCity"`).  These are all inside UI Bootstrap [`<accordion>`](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion).  In the `<accordion-heading>` I want to show a message if any of the form validations related to the billing address fail.  But I have many inputs, and I want to avoid this currently bloated solution:

```
<accordion-heading>
    Billing Address &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': billingAccordionObj.open
                                             , 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !billingAccordionObj.open}">
    </i>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span class="field-validation-error" ng-show="saveForm['billName'].$error.required
                                                || saveForm['billAddress1'].$error.required
                                                || saveForm['billCity'].$error.required"
                                                ... all the other fields>
        Invalid Billing Address
    </span>
</accordion-heading>
```

Is there any more elegant way to have this summary appear for any error just associated with my `billingAddress` object?  Or am I stuck typing out all of the names of the input fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a form and use the `$error` property of the form validation instead of the validation for each single input field:

```
<form name="MyForm">
  <input name="name" ng-model="m.name" required>
  <input type="number" min="1" name="age" ng-model="m.age" required>
</form>
```

If you only got input fields with the `required` validation and no other validations you can do:

```
 <span ng-show="MyForm.$error.required.length">Invalid</span>
```

If other validations are present or you want a imo clean solution, define a filter to check if a form is valid:

```
app.filter('isInvalid', function() {
  return function(form) {
    return Object.keys(form.$error).length;
  }
})

 <span ng-show="MyForm | isInvalid">Invalid</span>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/h63atRf4m4qcFxnlD5JN?p=preview

**Edit**

If you only want to show the validation message if specific fields are invalid you could only do something like:

```
app.filter('validateFields', function() {
  return function(form, fields) {
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      if(form[fields[i]].$invalid) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
})

<div ng-show="!(MyForm | validateFields : ['street', 'city'])">Invalid</div>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Dn6Cb0XYHDOTmpMwKNpp?p=preview

Comment: Well, that would be fine, except that other parts of the form have other validations that I don't want to interact with the address.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Improved my answer and added a way to show the validation message only for specific fields. Hope it fits to your needs.

Comment: Yeah I guess refactoring into a function like this is about what I have to work with.  Thanks.